# How to dynamically disable PurgeCSS?

Tags: purge, css-purge

I'm using PurgeCSS alongside Vite and I would like to disable PurgeCSS for some stylesheets. It is possible thanks to comments `/* purgecss ignore */`but I'm importing some CSS from libs directly in chunked & lazy loaded JS files like :

`fancybox_controller.js`

```js
import 'fancybox/dist/scss/jquery.fancybox.scss'
import 'fancybox/dist/js/jquery.fancybox'

import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus'

export default class extends Controller {
  open() {
    $.fancybox({
      padding: 4,
      href: $(this.element).data('large'),
      helpers: {
        overlay: {
          locked: false
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Any way to disable PurgeCSS in that case ?

Comment: You want to purge the purgeCSS? Very meta.   A side note is if you get into a fight with a css element you can always add !important to the end of it and force it to over ride the previously loaded one.  Such as color:black !important;

Answer (score 0):

you can import your css that you ned inside an external css file like `app.css`

```
/*! purgecss start ignore */
@import "/public/css/bootstrap-5.2.3.min.css";
@import "/public/css/fontawsome.min.css";
/*! purgecss end ignore */
```

and import `app.css` inside your js `app.js` file
then put your js file inside content to be ignored

```
cssPurge({
   content: ['/public/js/app.js']
)}
```

`/* purgecss ignore */` some times not working for me then iam using  `/*! purgecss start ignore */ &  /*! purgecss end ignore */` and it works